# dc motor center rotating magnets

Tags: dc-motor

Why do dc motors have the magnets on the sides and the coils rotating in the middle? Why isn't it the opposite? The magnets rotating in the middle and the the coils static on the sides. Wouldn't it be better to rotate the magnets that are free of wires while the coils need to be connected to wires?

Comment: Compare the output of a generator with the armature producing the output current and an alternator with the stator producing the output current. Consider the brushes and the power transmitted in each case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Permanent magnet brushless DC motors usually have the magnets on the rotor and the coils on the stator.

However, a brush motor has a mechanical commutator to keep the Q-axis field vector in the right spot.  If the coils were on the rotor, you would have to bring the DC in, run it through a commutator attached to the shaft, and bring it back out to the coils on the stator.  So commutation is harder.

A PM BLDC motor has electronics to drive and commutate the coils correctly, so there's no extra complexity to having the magnets on the rotor.

Wikipedia has a pretty good graphic showing how the brush commutator works: [DC Brush Motor on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brushed_DC_electric_motor)

[image]

By Abnormaal - Own work, CC BY-SA 3.0, https://commons.wikimedia.org/w/index.php?curid=4087521

Answer (score 0):

> Why isn't it the opposite? The magnets rotating in the middle and the
>   the coils static on the sides.

That basically describes an AC motor; the stator is supplied with an alternating voltage and the magnet aligns with the rotating magnetic field produced by several stator coils. This can be found in brushless motors where 3 phase (or multiples thereof) stators are sequentially driven to produce a rotating magnetic field that the rotor magnet aligns with.

This means that powering from DC requires you to convert to a multiphase AC voltage and this is quite costly for cheapo motors used in toys etc..

However, if you have static magnets and a rotating coil(s) you can use the rotation of the rotor along with a simple commutator to alternate the rotor coil voltage: -

[image]